# Can any $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ be differentiable at a point?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that any function on $\mathbb N$ is continuous but is any function differentiable on $\mathbb N$?  For example if $f(x) = x^2, f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ and let $c = 2$, can we claim the derivative of $f(x)$ at $x = 2$ exists?

Clearly if we let $f'(x) = 2x$ is continuous on $\mathbb N$ and the definition of the limit for $f(x)$ at $x = 2$ is $4$:

$$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{x^2 - 4}{x-2} = \lim_{x\to 2} (x+2) = 4$$

Comment: What does $\lim_{x \to 2}$ even mean on the integers?

Comment: There is no such thing as differentiability for a function defined on $\mathbb N$.

Comment: (That being said, polynomials in particular do have a "derivative" regardless of what domain they are defined over. But that doesn't mean they have anything like an instantaneous rate of change.)

Comment: The answer is no. Let $S \subset \mathbb R$. In order for a function $f:S \to \mathbb R$ to be differentiable at a point $x \in S$, there must be an open interval $E$ such that $x \in E \subset S$. (Some authors, such as Rudin I believe, allow $E$ to be a half-open interval.)

Comment: You could define limits in $\mathbb{N}$ since it is a topological space. But it has a trivial topology - the discrete topology.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ does not have limit points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said that any function on $\mathbb N$ is continuous. So why is that?: Let $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ be any function and let $x_0 \in \mathbb N$. Let $\varepsilon >0$ and choose $\delta <1$, say $\delta = \frac{1}{2}$. Then for every $x \in \mathbb N$ with $|x-x_0| < \delta < 1$, we have $x = x_0$, so $|f(x) - f(x_0)| = 0 < \varepsilon$.

So, you see that the definition of continuity makes perfect sense over $\mathbb N$. More generally, one can define a continuous function between any two topological spaces. A topological space is a set together with an distinguished set of subsets (satisfying certain properties with respect to set operations) which are called the "open sets". But this word "open" should not mislead you: In general, these open sets do not have to look like what our intuition of "open" is in $\mathbb R$. However, a possible choice for open sets in $\mathbb R$ are all unions of open intervals. With these open sets you get the usual notion of continuity on $\mathbb R$.

Now the canonical choice of open sets in $\mathbb N$ are all sets being open (in particular one-point-sets). This is also what is inherited from $\mathbb R$ and its unions of open intervals. This is because if you take intervals small enough and intersect them with $\mathbb N$ then you will get one-point sets. And that's exactly what we used in the proof of the continuity above.

In general, a set where you choose as distinguished open sets all subsets (so in particular one-point-sets) is called a "discrete space". With a similar argument as for $\mathbb N$, one sees that a function starting at a discrete space is always continuous, simply because points that are close together must be equal.

Let's come to differentiable functions: How is differentiability at a point $x_0$ defined? There exists $\alpha$ such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that for all $x$ with $|x-x_0| < \delta$ we have $|\alpha - \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}| < \varepsilon$. And this definition should reflect how the function changes for small $\delta$. Now, note that over $\mathbb N$ for $\delta < 1$, the same thing as above happens: We must have $x_0 = x$. But now the fraction $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ makes no sense at all.

Speaking more practical, the reason why differentiability makes no sense over discrete spaces like $\mathbb N$ with its usual open sets is that one cannot approximate a point $x_0$ arbitrarily well without already reaching the point (and therefore asking how the function changes locally makes no sense). For this one needs a topological space without isolated points (that is, no one-point-sets are open). But maybe even in this setting one runs in troubles in general.

Usually, to the best of my knowlegde, differentiable functions are defined over manifolds. A bit imprecise, these are topological spaces that around each point of them "look" like a copy of $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$ and these copies fit together nicely. If around each point you have a ball that looks like a ball in $\mathbb R^n$, then the definition of a differentiable function works out like in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for a function to be continuous or differentiable at a point, the function must be defined in a neighbourhood of that point. This is not the case in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Continuity has no such requirement. At all.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as currently written, for the reason that Arthur mentioned.